# Not found issue with ZenCart 1.3.9H

Tags: php, module

I'm having a strange issue that I'm trying to solve for the past hours but I don't seem to succeed.

I've installed a payment module that is working in other installations. However, in this one I get that an ajax file couldnt be found and therefore the module breaks severely. The interesting thing is that the file is there and I can open it directly in the web browser but still chrome gives me a 404 not found when called from the javascript as ajax.

Here you can see the file that exists: http://www.chipper.se/sveaAjax.php

And if you try to make a purchase on the homepage here: http://www.chipper.se/, on the step where you are about to choose payment, you will notice the file missing error.

I check with the .htaccess and there are no issues there.

The module support team are clueless as well. Any suggestions on things to try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this has probably to do with the cross-domain policy.

Adding

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200);
```

In the file that calls the javascript file solved the issue.